# How to prevent mmenu's default off-canvas menu display on large screens

Tags: mmenu

I'm using mmenu.js with Foundation 6.2 and want to prevent mmenu's off-canvas default menu display on large screen sizes. Foundation's visiblity classes are used to hide the off-canvas menu for large screens, where an on-canvas menu takes over. However, if the off-canvas menu is not closed prior to resizing the browser window to a large screen size, a blank space persists where the menu would be positioned. Is there a way to prevent the off-canvas API from displaying entirely at large screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that was helpful using window.matchMedia explained by Craig Butler at http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/. This causes the blank window space to close up (or rather slide close with the default mmenu setting) and the browser content to expand to full width at 1024px.

```
          $(document).ready(function() {            //Off canvas mmenu options
          $("#igreens").mmenu({

          navbar:{
                  title: ''
            }

            });
             var API = $("#igreens").data( "mmenu" );

            $("#nav-toggle").click(function() {
            API.open();

            });
                                                   // media query event handler
            if (matchMedia) {
                var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");
                mq.addListener(WidthChange);
                WidthChange(mq);
            }

            // media query change
            function WidthChange(mq) {
              if (mq.matches) {         
              API.close();                                   

              } else {                             // window width is less than 1024px
                mq.preventDefault();
              }
            }
         });
```